# Display data from tableviewcell into Pop-up UIView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uiview

I have a tableView showing multiple tasks already created by the user. When the user click on a task (tableView cell) i want to present a pop-up showing more info about the user's task. I already created the popUp view and it's showing fine but the data (category, date, hour) is not showing inside the popUp. I don't know how to access my data and put it into the pop-up View when the user click on the row. Here's what i tried so far :

**MyTasksCollectionCell**

```
enum DisplayedTasks {
    case current
    case past
}
class MyTasksCollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var displayedTasks = DisplayedTasks.current

var tasks = [Add]()
var pastTasks = [Add]()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath) as! MyTasksTableCell
    cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
    let task = {() -> Add in
        switch (displayedTask) {
          case .current:
             // First segment tapped
            return self.tasks[indexPath.row]
          case past:
             // Second segment tapped
            return self.pastTasks[indexPath.row]
        }
    }()
         
    cell.categoryLabel.text =
        "\(task.category)"
    cell.dateLabel.text =
        "\(task.date)"
    cell.hourLabel.text =
        "\(task.hour)"

    return cell
      
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
                 tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
 let task = {() -> Add in
        switch (displayedTask) {
          case .current:
             // First segment tapped
            return self.tasks[indexPath.row]
          case past:
             // Second segment tapped
            return self.pastTasks[indexPath.row]
        }
    }()
let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? MyTasksDetailView//Warning message here !!! "Cast from 'UITableViewCell?' to unrelated type 'MyTasksDetailView' always fails"

selectedCell?.category.text = "\(task.category)"
selectedCell?.hour.text = "\(task.hour)"
selectedCell?.date.text = "\(task.date)"
print (selectedCell?.category.text)
    
    let popupView = MyTasksDetailView()
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(popupView)

}
extension UIApplication {
    var keyWindow: UIWindow? {
        // Get connected scenes
        return UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
            // Keep only active scenes, onscreen and visible to the user
            .filter { $0.activationState == .foregroundActive }
            // Keep only the first `UIWindowScene`
            .first(where: { $0 is UIWindowScene })
            // Get its associated windows
            .flatMap({ $0 as? UIWindowScene })?.windows
            // Finally, keep only the key window
            .first(where: \.isKeyWindow)
    }
}
```

**MyTasksDetailView**

```
class MyTasksDetailView: UIView  {
      
     var setCategory: String? {
        didSet {
            categoryLabel.text = setCategory ?? ""
        }
    }
    var setDate: String? {
        didSet {
            dateLabel.text = setDate ?? ""
        }
    }
      var setHour: String? {
        didSet {
            hourLabel.text = setHour ?? ""
        }
    }
     let categoryLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 28, weight: .bold)
//        label.text = "category"
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.textColor = .label

        return label
    }()

     let dateLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18, weight: .bold)
//        label.text = "date"
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.numberOfLines = 3
        label.textColor = .label
        return label
    }()
let hourLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18, weight: .bold)
//        label.text = "hour"
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.numberOfLines = 3
        label.textColor = .label
        return label
    }()
     let container: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.clipsToBounds = true
        v.backgroundColor = .white
        v.layer.cornerRadius = 24

        v.backgroundColor =
            // 1
            UIColor { traitCollection in
              // 2
              switch traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle {
              case .dark:
                // 3
                 v.layer.borderColor = UIColor.label.cgColor
                return UIColor.systemBackground

              default:
                // 4
                 v.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
                return UIColor.systemBackground
              }
            }
        return v
    }()

     lazy var stack: UIStackView = {
        let stack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [categoryLabel, dateLabel, hourLabel])
        stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stack.axis = .vertical
        return stack
    }()
    @objc func animateOut() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
            self.container.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: -self.frame.height)
            self.alpha = 0
        }) { (complete) in
            if complete {
                self.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }
    }
    @objc func animateIn() {
        self.container.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: -self.frame.height)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
            self.container.transform = .identity
            self.alpha = 1
        })
    }
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(animateOut)))
       
        let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .dark)
        let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
        blurEffectView.frame = bounds
        blurEffectView.alpha = 1
        blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        self.addSubview(blurEffectView)
        
        self.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
        self.addSubview(container)
      
        container.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        container.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        container.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.7).isActive = true
        container.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.45).isActive = true
        
        container.addSubview(stack)
        stack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        stack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        stack.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        stack.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.5).isActive = true
        
        animateIn()
     }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

**Add (DataStruct)**

```
struct Add {
    static var details: Add = Add()
    var category: String = ""
    var date: String = ""
    var hour: String = ""
    var id: String?
    
    func getDict() -> [String: Any] {
              let dict = ["category": self.category,
                          "date": self.date,
                          "hour": self.hour,
                ] as [String : Any]
               return dict
         }

}
```

Comment: This looks very much like your previous question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70292528/programmaticallypush-a-viewcontroller-when-selecting-tableview-row-embedded-in ... and the answer I gave you there should be pretty much the same as for this question. And there is no reason to be doing any of this: `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(popupView)`

Comment: @DonMag I changed my code to present a pop-up (more practical) but it makes your code non-usable because it's not a viewController anymore, also i tried using your code but could'nt make it work with mine :/ PS: `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(popupView)` Without this the popUp only show inside the tableView  bottom of the screen) instead of the middle of the screen...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see where you set needed data to your MyTasksDetailView.

Add property "task" to MyTasksDetailView (cant find type of your task instance so in my example I used Task)

```
internal var task: Task? {
   didSet {
        if let task = task {
            setCategory = task.category
            setDate = task.date
            setHour =  task.hour
        }
    }
}
```

And set it after init

```
let popupView = MyTasksDetailView()
popupView.task = task
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(popupView)
```

Comment: I added the property inside the **MyTasksDetailView** and added the `popupView.task = task` inside my didselect but there is an error sayin "Cannot find 'task' in scope"

Comment: If all you need is to show popupView with cell data, you can remove code with selectedCell and setting of its properties (this won't work because you try to cast cell to your custom view, when all you can is to cast to MyTasksTableCell, as you set it in CellForRaw).
"Cannot find 'task' in scope" - do this in scope where you define "task" constant.

Comment: Nevermind it's working ! Thank you !